# How to recall the answer of an if statement in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement

I am writing a function, which is suppose to give the result of the following if statement:

```
s=some scalar
i=some scalar ; 
    if  y(s,i)==L 
        U(1,i)==0 
    else disp('Never binding') ;
    end
```

How can I store the "answer" so that the name given to the answer is the output of the function?

for example: ans=R and function R=myfunction(i,s)

Is this possible?

for example if i run my code:

```
if y(8,1)==L 
    U(1,1)==0 
else disp('Never binding') 
end
```

ans =

X1_2*a - P1_2*X1_2 - X1_2^2*b + X1_2*(LL*(g1_2 + g2_1) + LL*(g1_3 + g3_1)) == 0

or another case:

```
if y(1,1)==L 
    U(1,1)==0 
else disp('Never binding') 
end 
Never binding
```

Here is the code for the complete function:

```
function R=myIR1(s, n , agent)

x = 'HL';                 %// Set of possible types
K = n;                      %// Length of each permutation

%// Create all possible permutations (with repetition) of letters stored in x
C = cell(K, 1);             %// Preallocate a cell array
[C{:}] = ndgrid(x);         %// Create K grids of values
y = cellfun(@(x){x(:)}, C); %// Convert grids to column vectors
y = [y{:}];
e=size(y,1);

X = sym('X',[n e], 'positive' );
P = sym('P',[n e], 'positive' );
G=sym('g' , [n,n]) ;
syms c a b ;

s=s;

A = char( zeros(n,2*n) ) ;
    for col=1:n
        Acol = [col col+1] + (col-1) ; 
        A(:,Acol)   = [ y(s,col)*ones(n,1) y(s,:).' ] ; 
    end
A1 = reshape( cellstr( reshape(A.',2,[]).' ) , n , n ).' ;

B=A1.*(G+G') ;
B(logical(eye(size(B)))) = 0 ;

for i=1:n
     U(i)=[a*X(i,s) - b*(X(i,s))^2 + X(i,s)*(sum(B(:,i).*X(:,s))) - X(i,s)*P(i,s)];
end

agent=agent ;


syms H L ;

i=agent ; 
if y(s,i)==L 
    U(1,i)==0 
else disp('Never binding') ;
end
```

IR is not assigned to anything, I want to assign it to the answer of the if statement..

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as an  `if` loop.

Comment: @Ratbert - Probably meant `if` statement....?

Comment: What is the "answer" in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just assign `R` to be whatever you want inside the function body.  When the function terminates, whatever `R` was assigned to is the final output that gets sent back to the user.

For example:

```
function R = myfunction(i,s)

...
...
...
R = ... ;%// Assign the value of R you want here
...
...
end
```

Then in the MATLAB Command Prompt, you would do:

```
R = myfunction(i,s);
```

When calling this function, `R` will contain whatever you assigned it to be in the function itself.  However, you need to **make sure** that `R` gets assigned to something before the function terminates.  If you don't, then MATLAB will give you an error telling you that you forgot to assign `R` something as it's expected to be the output.

---

Given your code, it looks like the main assignment that you want to store is done in the `if` statement at the end of your code.  You're actually not storing that assignment to a variable.  In particular:

```
if y(s,i)==L 
    U(1,i)==0 
else disp('Never binding') ;
end
```

If you don't assign a variable to something, it automatically gets stored in a variable called `ans`, which is what you're echoing to the command prompt as you're not placing a semi-colon in front of the `U(1,i) == 0` statement.  I believe you want to take this output and assign it to `R` as `R` is the final output variable you want, so just do this.  Note that your output variable is called `IR` and **not `R`** so make sure you change the output variable to `R` in the function:

```
if y(s,i)==L 
    R = U(1,i) == 0;
else disp('Never binding') ;
end
```

Place a semi-colon at the end of the statement so it doesn't unnecessarily echo the output to the screen.

Comment: thank you for your help but precisely I can't seem to assign R to the answer of the if loop, because it is not stored as an entry of a vector or cell.. is this possible?

Comment: @Sha - I don't understand your statement.  Please show more of your code.  I'm very confused.

Comment: thank you, I edited my question to show more of the code. thank you very much

Comment: Your variable `U` is not assigned to anything.  Did you mean to do `R = U(1,i) == 0;`?

Comment: I tried this but it returns an error: 
Output argument "R" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "myIR1". Although for this error I wrote R=U(1,i)==0

Comment: @Sha - Your output variable is called `IR` **not `R`**.

Comment: thank you very much for your help; the function now returns the answer but it displays an error still: R=myIR1(1, 3 , 1)
Never binding
Error in myIR1 (line 3)
x = 'HL';                 %// Set of possible types

Output argument "R" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "myIR1". Ichanged IR into R all along.

Comment: Stop changing your code.  Now your code has changed the output variable to `R`.  **Leave the output variable in the function untouched and just assign your answer to this variable**.  Now, use my answer and change the output to `R`, not `IR`.

Comment: @Sha - Great.  Looks like you figured it out.  Good luck!